# How to tokenize grammars, like in monaco.editor.tokenize for use in extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have used the [tokenizer](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#functions/editor.tokenize.html) in monaco but I do not see that it is accessible in vscode.  This would be helpful for completion/signature help providers, how can I tokenize a grammar?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there's an official way of doing this right now. There is an open feature request for adding the ability to retrieve tmLanguage scopes at a position here: [#580](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/580)

There is one potential workaround, which requires adding a dependency to the [scope-info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.scope-info) extension. This extension exposes an API of its own that other extension can use. Here's a code example [posted by the author](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/580#issuecomment-267110992) in the linked issue:

```ts
import * as api from 'scope-info'
async function example(doc : vscode.TextDocument, pos: vscode.Position) {
    const siExt = vscode.extensions.getExtension<api.ScopeInfoAPI>('siegebell.scope-info');
    const si = await siExt.activate();
    const t1 : api.Token = si.getScopeAt(doc, pos);
}
```

**Update:** unfortunately, it looks like scope-info is [no longer compatible with current VSCode versions](https://github.com/siegebell/scope-info/issues/5).

Answer (score 0):

The following code tokenizes a document, caches that result and sends it back to the extension :)

```js
import TextmateLanguageService from 'vscode-textmate-languageservice';

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const selector: vscode.DocumentSelector = '<LANGUAGE>';
    const textmateService = new TextmateLanguageService('LANGUAGE', context);
    const textmateTokenService = await textmateService.initTokenService();
    const textDocument = vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.document;
    const tokens = textmateTokenService.fetch(textDocument);
};
```

This is my library - soon doable without context parameter..