# Get language specific scope from current cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Given this json file is open in the editor:

```
[
  <--here
]
```

And my cursors is at the marked position, how do I get the information that it is inside an array?

```
let editor = window.activeTextEditor as TextEditor;
let selection = editor.selection;
```

I am getting the selection of the cursor, but the `editor.document` does not seem to provide an AST or service to retrieve the document language specific scope the cursor is within.

`vscode.languages` also does not offer any API that I could query using the documents `languageId` which is set correctly to `json`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113929/how-to-tokenize-grammars-like-in-monaco-editor-tokenize-for-use-in-extension/45116516#45116516

Comment: Time to write another plugin that provides such functionality maybe ;)